# Inlined thymeleaf variable gets evaluated to null

Tags: javascript, thymeleaf

I've looked through current answers but couldn't find any similar and suggested answers did not resolve my issue.

I have this in my template:

```
<bulb:infomessage key="COMPARE_LIST_FULL" var="comparelistfull"/>
<script th:inline="javascript" th:if="${comparelistfull != null}">
    /*<![CDATA[*/
    notificationMessages.fullCompare   = /*[[${comparelistfull}]]*/;
    /*]]>*/
</script>
```

The first line is child of AbstractElementProcessor which adds model variable named 'comparelistfull'.

what I get after processing:

```
<script>
    /*<![CDATA[*/
    notificationMessages.fullCompare   = null;
    /*]]>*/
</script>
```

I do realize that the cause of this might be the order of processing (the value on the right hand side is processed before the th:if block), but I have no clue where to fix this...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28633329/how-to-serialize-pojo-with-thymeleaf), it might be related. What result do you have without `/*<![CDATA[*/ /*]]>*/` ?

Comment: @heRoy it's the same with or without CDATA part. I have seen that post before and tried the suggestions, but no use... comparelistfull in my example is always a string.