# Thymeleaf print JSON string as JSON object into a javascript variable

Tags: java, javascript, json, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

**In Specific**

I need a way to print `JSON` representation of a string value into the html page via thymeleaf.

**In detail**

I'm having a `model attribute` which contains a string which is actually a string representation of the `JSON`

My `thymeleaf` code

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
  var value = [[${data.scriptValue}]];
</script>
```

print the variable as below

```
var value = '[[\"asd\",\"3\"],[\"asd\",\"1\"],[\"asdasd\",\"1\"]]';
```

But I want something like this as a `javascript/JSON` array

```
var value = [["asd","3"],["asd","1"],["asdasd","1"]];
```

How to do this in thymeleaf?

---

*Note: I know I can do this from `JSON.Parse` but i need a way to do this from thymeleaf :)*

Comment: I think this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28633329/how-to-serialize-pojo-with-thymeleaf/28691655#28691655 and this http://forum.thymeleaf.org/Spring-Javascript-and-escaped-JSON-td4024739.html would help

Comment: Thanks @PatrickLC I'm actually doing this at the moment as I mentioned in the question. But won't it be great to have a direct method in thymeleaf to do this like `th:utext` :)

Comment: I agree that would be something useful, you could find two related issues: https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/issues/12 and https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/issues/81

Answer (score 29, accepted):

*Update - 2015/12/24*

This feature is **available in Thymeleaf 3**

Refer `The Thymeleaf textual syntax` in https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/issues/395

```
// Unescaped (actual answer)
var value = [(${data.scriptValue})];
//or
var value = [# th:utext="${data.scriptValue}"/];

// Escaped
var value = [[${data.scriptValue}]];
//or
var value = [# th:text="${data.scriptValue}"/];
```

---

**It's not possible at Thymeleaf 2.** As Patric LC mentioned, there are two issues reported for this.

1. [unescaped inline for scripts/css #12](https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/issues/81)
2. [Use Jackson for Javascript inlining of JSON #81](https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/issues/81)

Answer (score 5):

@Faraj, new version of Thymeleaf provides this functionality. They implement features for the issues that you mentioned. You can look here:
http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/thymeleaf3migration.html

The main features:

- Three textual template modes: TEXT, JAVASCRIPT and CSS.
- New syntax for elements in textual template modes: `[# ...] ... [/]`.
- Inlined output expressions allowed, both escaped `([[...]])` and unescaped `([(...)])`.
- Intelligent escaping of JavaScript (as literals) and CSS (as identifiers).
- Parser-level `(/*[- ... -]*/)` and prototype-only `(/*[+ ... +]*/)` comment blocks.
- Natural templates applied to JAVASCRIPT scripts and CSS style sheets by means of wrapping elements and/or output expressions inside comments `(/*[# ...]*/)`.