# How to ouput a json string in the js section of a html file using thymeleaf

Tags: java, escaping, thymeleaf, templating

I have a project with Java 8, bringing data to the frontend with Thymeleaf. The data entity I want to ouput in my frontend is calles `logs` and is a list of entities that have an attribute containig json data. I output it in the html file as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    let logs = [[${logs}]];
</script>
```

The json has the following structure:

```
{
  "oldest": 712367620,
  "youngest": 712378606,
  "measurements": []
}
```

But on the page it appears with the double quotes escaped which completely messes up the js:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    let logs = [LogEntity(id=52, success=true, runtimes={
        &quot;oldest&quot; : 712367620,
        &quot;youngest&quot; : 712378606,
        &quot;measurements&quot; : []
    })]
</script>
```

How can I prevent the escaping of the double quotes in the json string?
I work with php and twig in another project and there it is as simple as `{{ logs|raw }}`. Is there some kind of modifier in thymeleaf like `|raw` in php twig?

Security is not an issue since I have complete control over the data objects.

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable [JavaScript inlining](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#javascript-inlining) with `th:inline="javascript"`:

```
<script type="text/javascript" th:inline="javascript">
    let logs = [[${logs}]];
</script>
```

(I'm not sure what you mean by "json data".  Do you mean you have a `String` that contains JSON?)

Comment: Exactly. The attribute `runtimes` is a string that contains json

Comment: Your code gives me

 `<script type="text/javascript">
  let logs = "{\r\n  \"oldest\" : 752646765,\r\n  \"youngest\" : 752747578,\r\n  \"measurements\" : []\r\n}";
 </script>`

which I would need without the backslashes before the double quotes and without the `\r\n`

Comment: I found the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29733594/thymeleaf-print-json-string-as-json-object-into-a-javascript-variable